# IntelliJ IDEA: Jump from interface to implementing method in Go

Tags: go, intellij-idea, interface, keyboard-shortcuts, goland

In IntilliJ Idea/Goland, Is there any shortcut that would allow me to select a method inside interface definition and jump to implementation of that method or give me list of implementations.

I am looking for something like what I get when <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+Click and get usage of the methods/function.

[image: View After Cmd+Click]

But instead of usage of method I need short cut for implementation. Currently I have to copy the method name and search in the project, which does not feels like most efficient way.

I am using intelliJ Idea (Community Edition) 2016.2.2 EAP with [Go plugin](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org) Version: 0.12.1724.

I have tried <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> but always getting `No implementation found`

Comment: Never used IntelliJ, though for Go I would recommend [vscode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode), it has an awesome Go plugin, plus the 100% open source.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This support has been added in Goland (or with go plugin in IntelliJ ultimate) now. Shortcut for the same is `Alt+Cmd+B` (`Option+Cmd+B` for Mac).

[image]

Comment: On Windows it's `Ctrl+Alt+B`.

Answer (score 2):

For goland

Windows: `Alt+Cmd+B`
Mac os: `Option+Cmd+B`

Answer (score 1):

No, such shortcut doesn't exist.

You can use "Find Usage" to determine where the specific interface method is used, but if you want to see all the concrete implementations the current way is to search the entire project for the method name.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the keymap settings, if you use Visual Studio keymap like me, the shortcuts will be a bit different:   `Options+End` on Mac does the thing (GoLand 2022.2). IntelliJ keymap is `Options+Cmd+B`.

[image]

You can find your shortcut by searching action `Go to implementation`, see:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For GoLand you can follow the available keyboard [shortcuts](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/goland/docs/GoLand_ReferenceCard.pdf) which is provided in the GoLand official [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html). It is possible to jump to the method implementations using `Ctrl + Alt + B` (windows/linux).

Same command also works for Intellij IDEA. You can find all available keyboard [shortcuts](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) here.